# How to sink json data with keys in Uppercase into Postgres table?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

Let's say I have a topic (user) that has json data but with no schema.

Data example:

```
{"id":3151212170,"name":"John Wick"}
```

To tackle this, I created a stream (user_stream) to take the data from the topic and basically give it a schema.

```
create stream user_stream (id bigint, name string) with (kafka_topic='user', value_format='JSON', key = 'id');
```

Then to consume the data I created another stream:

```
create stream user_final with (value_format = 'AVRO') as select * from USER_STREAM;
```

Note: The data is now in Avro format with a schema but the Columns are now in Uppercase.

I am using Kafka's JdbcSinkConnector to Sink Data into an already existing Postgres Table.

Postgres Table Example:

```
create table mytable (id bigint primary key, name text)
```

Sink Connector Configuration:

```
{
    "name": "postgres-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "USER_FINAL",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-reg-url:8081",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-reg-url:8081",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres-url:5432/mydbname?user=username&password=password",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "table.name.format": "mytable",
        "pk.mode": "none",
        "insert.mode": "insert"
    }
}
```

The problem is that the stream column names are in **Uppercase**, whereas Postgres table's column names are in **Lowercase**. Even if I create a table in Postgres with uppercase column names it just converts to Lowercase.

Error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "ID" of relation "mytable" does not exist
```

Is there a workaround for this? I'm open to suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even if I create a table in Postgres with uppercase column names it
>   just converts to Lowercase.

If your column names are not placed in double quotes, PostgreSQL will convert them to their lower case format.

Therefore,

- Quotes make the column names case-sesintive
- whereas unquoted column names are always folded to lower case

---

On Kafka Connect side, you can change the field names using [Kafka Connect Single Message Transofrms (SMT)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html).

More precisely, [`ReplaceField`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html#replacefield) lets you rename fields. For example, the following transformation will replace column names `COL1` and `COL2` to `col1` and `col2` respectively:

```
"transforms": "RenameField",
"transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.RenameField.renames": "COL1:col1,COL2:col2"
```

Comment: If I do so, I will have to use double quotes when I query the table. I'm trying to avoid using double quotes every single time I run a query. Please correct me if I am wrong or understood wrong.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I will accept it as it works for me now. But what do I do if I have a lot of columns?

Comment: @TchiringLama Simply write a small script to build this kind of string: `"COL1:col1,COL2:col2"` :)